# a trouble in using "UIView animateWithDuration:......"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm having a trouble in animation. here is some codes:

```
//wobbling cells in collection view controller
if (_isEdit){
    myCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-0.01);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.12
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^{
                         myCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.01);
                     } completion:nil];
}
```

What I want is when the "_isEdit == YES;" cells wobbling.

But if I push to another ViewController when the cells wobbling, 
then dismiss. The animation stop ("_isEdit" is still "YES")...

How can I keep the animation working?

Comment: use `self.isEdit` and then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly you can just call the method again in viewDidAppear, and it should start again.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

If the code is from:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

then you could try just reloading the tableView by calling reloadData on the tableView in the viewDidAppear method. If the _isEdit is still equal to YES then the animation should trigger again.

Comment: You could try calling it from different parts of the view controller life cycle, like viewWillAppear. If this doesn't suit you, you might have to rethink your structure (Also if it works, this should be marked as the answer).